# Django: HTTP 500 on ajax file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I'm trying to upload a photo in django using jquery ajax. However, I keep getting an HTTP 500.

Here's the js file:

```
$("#photo-input").change(function() {
    var data = new FormData($(this).get(0));

    $.ajax({
        url: '/upload_photo/',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(json) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function(json) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

and here's the view:

```
def upload_photo(request):
    if request.POST:
        photo = request.FILES['data']

        response_data = {}
        response_data['photo'] = photo

        return HttpResponse (
            json.dumps(response_data),
            content_type='application/json'
        )
```

I've seen many examples like this, but I keep getting an HTTP 500. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use Postman to see what error Django spits out

Comment: What is the exacterror that django gives?